# Getting the current sbt plugin cross version

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-0.13, sbt1.0

I'm trying to cross-build an sbt plugin between `0.13` and `1.1`. To accomplish this I need to use different `libraryDependencies` for the different builds, but I can't find a way to access the current build's target sbt version.

Back when the cross compilation was in a plugin there was `CrossBuilding.pluginSbtVersion` but I can't find anything similar anymore.

- `sbtVersion.value` always gives me `0.13.16`
- `(sbtVersion in sbtPlugin)` likewise
- `crossVersion` always gives me `Binary`
- `scalaBinaryVersion` always gives me `2.10`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was present in sbt's output all along:

```
[info] Setting `sbtVersion in pluginCrossBuild` to 1.1.2
```

I just had to use `(sbtBinaryVersion in pluginCrossBuild).value`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  sbtBinaryVersion.value match {
    case "0.13" => Seq(...)
    case "1.0" => Seq(...)
  }
}
```

make sure to run your sbt commands with `^`, to run command on all sbt versions, ie:

```
sbt "^compile"
```

Comment: For some reason that gives `0.13` all the time as well :/

Comment: have you defined `crossSbtVersions := Vector("0.13.17", "1.1.4")` ?

Comment: Yes. I found out how to solve my issue though. See my answer. Thanks anyway!